# <img> in <a> crashes app (Javascript Windows 8 app)

Tags: javascript, html, windows-store-apps

Basically what the title says. I have an anchor tag `<a>` hooked up with the PageControl, following the tutorial. I set the anchor tag to `display:block` and then added an `<img>` inside the `<a>`.
However, clicking the `<img>` will cause the app to crash. If I click the area around the `<img>` (but inside the `<a>`), the link works. It's just the `<img>` that's weird.

I tried Googling the issue but couldn't find a solution. If this has been asked before, a link would be extremely helpful.

EDIT: Here's the offending code:

```
<a id="MainGrid" href="/pages/flow/flow.html">
    <img src="/images/Documents.png" />
    <br />
    New Round
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out the problem and I'm posting it here for future reference.

The tutorial asks us to add this function:

```
linkClickEventHandler: function (eventInfo) {
    eventInfo.preventDefault();
    var link = eventInfo.target;
    WinJS.Navigation.navigate(link.href, { isReal: false });
}
```

Apparently, the problem is the variable `link` is targeting the image, instead of the actual anchor tag. I just added some logic that checks if link is an anchor tag (and if not, I set `link = link.parentElement;` and everything works now.

Thanks to everyone who actually bothered to take the time and tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and check to see if you are closing your img tag properly. I've run into really random problems in html when i forgot the add a '/'

Your code should like something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" target="_self"> 
   <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Tutorials Point" border="0"/> 
</a>
```